# Join tuple and dataframe together

Tags: python

I have a tuple and a dataframe.  I would like to convert the tuple into a dataframe and then join it to my existing dataframe.  I tried the following:

```
pandas.DataFrame(tuple_data, columns=["Status", "Follow up length"])
```

It returned an empty dataframe.

My dataframe:

```
{'afb': {0: '1', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0', 5: '0', 6: '0', 7: '0', 8: '0', 9: 
'0'}, 'age': {0: 83.0, 1: 49.0, 2: 70.0, 3: 70.0, 4: 70.0, 5: 70.0, 6: 57.0, 7: 55.0, 
8: 88.0, 9: 54.0}, 'av3': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0', 5: '1', 6: '0', 7: '0', 8: '0', 9: '0'}}
```

Tuple data:

```
[[false, 2178.0], [false, 2172.0], [false, 2190.0], [true, 297.0], [false, 2131.0], [true, 1.0], [false, 2122.0], [true, 1496.0], [true, 920.0], [false, 2175.0]]
```

Comment: tuple_data is not a valid python list. What is its datatype?

Comment: it is a numpy array

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not either " " the true and false or use uppercase?
Then it would be worth having a look at the zip function:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip